# Always show certain activity when the app is started (and not when navigating from activity to activity)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this problem that I want to show a lock-screen when the app is opened/started, then the user types a pin in the lock-screen and then the app can be used as normal (no more lock-screen).

I thought I solved this by starting the lock-screen activity when onPause/onResume is called in every activity, but by doing that the app will of course navigate back to the lock-screen activity when any activity is started/paused (bad idea).

I have been thinking of setting a sharedpref value that indicates if the user has unlocked the lock-screen activity or not.

**However I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem, or how to run some code ONLY when the app is opened/reopened or stopped/paused?**

Comment: `I have been thinking of setting a sharedpref value that indicates if the user has unlocked the lock-screen activity or not.` yes. do this

Comment: Well, basically your OnCreate in your MainActivity is called only when the app is opened. You can call the LockScreen from there and from the LockScreen you can navigate to where ever you want. Using a sharedPref is optional but you'll need to set it to false when user exists the app. You can also put a timer when onPause, if it's been more than X seconds only then open LockScreen. Also, you can simply call the LockScreen activity with a parameter to indicate which activity to navigate back to, upon inserting the password/pin/w.e

Comment: That's a good point that I still need to know when the app enters the background/paused, I figured out how to this, and ended up using an approach where I set a sharedpref value to "locked" when the app enters the background.